# set button color programmatically

Tags: android, button, background, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am setting button background color. my button is generated from array value and create layout using recyclerview and cardview. everything works fine color is set on click of button. when I am click on first button 'D' it set background but there is automatically set to button 'M' which is not click and go on next button click 'E' same automatically set background to button 'N' and so on .  it automatically set color to button after 9th position button M,N,O........

here is my fragment class.

```
    public class Cart_fragment extends Fragment {
    public static ImageView img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8,img9,img10;
    public static String [] colorarray={"D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O-P","Q-R","S-T","U-V","W-X","Y-Z"};
    public static String [] clarity={"IF","FL","VVS1","VVS2","VS1","VS2","SI1","SI2","SI3","I1","I2","I3"};
    public static String [] cut={"IDL","EX","VG","GD","FR","PR"};
    public static String [] polish={"EX","VG","GD","FR","PR","POLISH"};
    public static String [] symmetry={"EX","VG","GD","FR","PR","SYMM"};
    public static String [] fluorance={"NON","VSLT","SLT","FNT","MED","STG"};
    public static String [] lab={"GIA","IGI","HRD","OWN","EGL"};
    public static String [] location={"MUMBAI","MUMBAI1","MUMBAI2","SURAT"};
    public static String [] Intensity={"DEEP","FAINT","FANCY","FANCY DARK","FANCY DEEP","FANCY VIVID","FANCY INTENSE",
            "FANCY LIGHT","LIGHT","VERYLIGHT"};
    public static String [] overtone={"YELLOWISH","BROWNISH","BROWNISH GREEN","BLUISH","GRAYISH","GRAYISH YELLOWISH","GRAYISH GREENISH",
            "GREENISH","PINKISH","PURPLISH"};
    public static String [] colorfancy={"BROWN","YELLOW","GREEN","PINK","GRAY","BLUE","GREEN YELLOW","ORANGE BROWN","YELLOW GREEN"};
    RadioGroup radg;
    RadioButton white,fancy;
    String flag="true";
    String flag2="false";
    String flag3="normal";
    View rootView;
    int counter=0;
    Recyleradapter adapter;
    LinearLayout fancyshow,whitehide;
    RecyclerView recyclerView, clarityrecylerview,cutrecyler,polishrecyler,symmetryrecyler,fluorancerecyler,
            labrecylerlab,loc_recyler,intensityrecylerview,overtonerecylerview,fancycolorrecylerview;
    List<String> colorlist;

      public static Cart_fragment newInstance() {
        Cart_fragment fragment = new Cart_fragment();
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartfrag, container, false);

        img1=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        img2=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img2);
        img3=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img3);
        img4=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img4);
        img5=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img5);
        img6=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img6);
        img7=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img7);
        img8=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img8);
        img9=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img9);
        img10=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img10);
        radg=(RadioGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.radgrp);
        white=(RadioButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.white);
        fancy=(RadioButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fancyradio);
        fancyshow=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fancy);
        whitehide=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.whitecolorhide);


        img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img1);
            }
        });
        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img2);
            }
        });
        img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img3);
            }
        });
        img4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img4);
            }
        });
        img5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img5);
            }
        });
        img6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img6);
            }
        });
        img7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img7);
            }
        });
        img8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img8);
            }
        });
        img9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img9);
            }
        });
        img10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addbackcolor(img10);
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.color_recyler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);

        clarityrecylerview = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.clarity_recyler);
        clarityrecylerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        clarityrecylerview.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer1);

        cutrecyler = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cut_recyler);
        cutrecyler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer2 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        cutrecyler.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer2);

        polishrecyler = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.polish_recyler);
        polishrecyler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer3 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        polishrecyler.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer3);

        symmetryrecyler = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.symmetry_recyler);
        symmetryrecyler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer4 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        symmetryrecyler.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer4);

        fluorancerecyler = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fluorance_recyler);
        fluorancerecyler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer5 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        fluorancerecyler.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer5);

        labrecylerlab = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lab_recyler);
        labrecylerlab.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer6 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        labrecylerlab.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer6);

        loc_recyler = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.loc_recyler);
        loc_recyler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer7 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        loc_recyler.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer7);

        intensityrecylerview = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.intensity_recyler);
        intensityrecylerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer8 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        intensityrecylerview.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer8);

        overtonerecylerview = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.overtone_recyler);
        overtonerecylerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer9 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        overtonerecylerview.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer9);

        fancycolorrecylerview = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.colorfancy_recyler);
        fancycolorrecylerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer10 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        fancycolorrecylerview.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer10);

        addarray(colorarray);
        addarray(clarity);
        addarray(cut);
        addarray(polish);
        addarray(symmetry);
        addarray(fluorance);
        addarray(lab);
        addarray(location);
        addarray(Intensity);
        addarray(overtone);
        addarray(colorfancy);
        white.setChecked(true);
        white.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                whitehide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fancyshow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        fancy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                whitehide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fancyshow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void addbackcolor(ImageView img1) {
        img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedbackground);
    }

    private void addarray(String[] colorarray) {
        colorlist = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < colorarray.length; i++) {
            colorlist.add(colorarray[i]);
        }
        addadapter(colorlist);
    }

    private void addadapter(List<String> colorlist) {
        if(counter==7){
            adapter = new Recyleradapter(getContext(),(ArrayList<String>) colorlist,flag);
        }else if(counter==8||counter==9||counter==10){
            adapter = new Recyleradapter(getContext(),(ArrayList<String>) colorlist,flag2);
        }else {
            adapter = new Recyleradapter(getContext(),(ArrayList<String>) colorlist,flag3);
        }

        counter++;
        addrecyler(adapter,counter);
    }

    private void addrecyler(Recyleradapter adapter, int counter) {
        int getcount=counter;
        if(getcount==1){
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==2){
            clarityrecylerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==3){
            cutrecyler.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==4){
            polishrecyler.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==5){
            symmetryrecyler.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==6){
            fluorancerecyler.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==7){
            labrecylerlab.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==8){
            loc_recyler.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==9){
            intensityrecylerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==10){
            overtonerecylerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else if (getcount==11){
            fancycolorrecylerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

here is adapter class where i am  create button according to size of array and setting background color .

adapter class

```
public class Recyleradapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recyleradapter.Viewholder> {
    Context ctx;
    String flag,colorstring;
    int counter = 0,counter2 = 0;

    View view;
    String [] buttonid = {"btnpex","btnpvg","btnpgd","btnpfr","btnppr",""};
    String [] buttonsymm={"btnsex","btnsvg","btnsgd","btnsfr","btnspr",""};
    StringBuffer result2color=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2clarity=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2cut=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2polish=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2symmetry=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2fluorance=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2lab=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2loca=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2intensity=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2overtone=new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer getResult2colorfancy=new StringBuffer();

    private ArrayList<String> countries;

    public Recyleradapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> countries, String flag) {
        this.ctx=context;
        this.flag=flag;
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    @Override
    public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(flag.equals("true")){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_listview1, parent, false);
        }else if (flag.equals("false")){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_listview2, parent, false);
        }else{
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_listview, parent, false);
        }
        return new Viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Viewholder holder, final int position) {
        final int    size = countries.size()-1;
        if(countries.contains("POLISH")){
            holder.tv_country.setTag(buttonid[position]);
        }
        if(countries.contains("SYMM")){
            holder.tv_country.setTag(buttonsymm[position]);
        }
        if ( countries.contains("POLISH") || countries.contains("SYMM")) {
            holder.tv_country.setText(countries.get(position));

            if (position == size) {
                countries.remove(position);
            }
        } else {
            holder.tv_country.setText(countries.get(position));
        }
        holder.tv_country.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            final String str = holder.tv_country.getText().toString().trim();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (holder.tv_country.getTag()!=null){
                        if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnpex")) {
                            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnpvg")){
                            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnpgd")){
                            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnpfr")){
                            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnppr")){
                            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                        if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnsex")) {
                            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnsvg")) {
                            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnsgd")) {
                            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnsfr")) {
                            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnspr")) {
                            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                }
                    for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.colorarray.length; i++) {
                        if (Cart_fragment.colorarray[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                            result2color.append(str + ",");
                            Log.e("iii", String.valueOf(i));
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.clarity.length; i++) {
                        if (Cart_fragment.clarity[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                            getResult2clarity.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.cut.length; i++) {
                        if (countries.get(0).equals("IDL") && Cart_fragment.cut[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                            getResult2cut.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.fluorance.length; i++) {
                        if (Cart_fragment.fluorance[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                            getResult2fluorance.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.lab.length; i++) {
                        if (Cart_fragment.lab[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                            getResult2lab.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.location.length; i++) {
                        if (Cart_fragment.location[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                            getResult2loca.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.Intensity.length; i++) {
                        if (Cart_fragment.Intensity[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                            getResult2intensity.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.overtone.length; i++) {
                        if (Cart_fragment.overtone[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                            getResult2overtone.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.colorfancy.length; i++) {
                        if (Cart_fragment.colorfancy[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                            getResult2colorfancy.append(str + ",");
                            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                        }
                    }

                Log.e("position", String.valueOf(position));
//                Log.e("countrer", String.valueOf(counter));
                Log.e("countrer2", String.valueOf(counter2));
                Log.e("whitecolor", result2color.toString());
                Log.e("clarity", getResult2clarity.toString());
                Log.e("cut", getResult2cut.toString());
                Log.e("polish", getResult2polish.toString());
                Log.e("symme", getResult2symmetry.toString());
                Log.e("lab", getResult2lab.toString());
                Log.e("locat", getResult2loca.toString());
                Log.e("flaoura", getResult2fluorance.toString());
                Log.e("intensity", getResult2intensity.toString());
                Log.e("overtone", getResult2overtone.toString());
                Log.e("fancycolor", getResult2colorfancy.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void addbackccolor(Button tv_country) {
        tv_country.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedbackground);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return countries.size();
    }

    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private Button tv_country;
        public Viewholder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_country = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an "else" for every "if" conditions in onBindViewHolder method that changes your background color and you should set your default background color in that.

edit:
also you should change all of your loops, for example replace it:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.location.length; i++) {
                    if (Cart_fragment.location[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                        getResult2loca.append(str + ",");
                        addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                    }
                }
```

with :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Cart_fragment.location.length; i++) {
                if (Cart_fragment.location[i].equals(str.toString().trim())) {
                    getResult2loca.append(str + ",");
                    addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
                }
               else
                  setDefaultBackColor(holder.tv_country);
            }
```

Comment: i add default background in last else outside button click it works but create issue when i scroll it it remove selected  button back ground

Comment: can you edit my code where to i put else part ?@REza.Abedini

Comment: please wait i'll add some description in my answer.

Comment: check it @Hasmukhkachhatiya

Comment: i try this but when i scroll my recylerview it change the selected button background@Reza.Abedini

Comment: ok it is because onBindView holder resets your view on scroll.you should have a boolean in your object , for example "isSelected" boolean. and set it  true when you select that item. then you can check isSelected boolean in your onBindViewHolder and set the color.

Comment: or you can have selected items in a boolean array and check it in onBindViewHolder method. @Hasmukhkachhatiya

Answer (score 1):

As a `RecyclerView` is reusing (recycling) its cells you need to set the color to the default again in `onBindViewHolder(...) {..}` in your Adapter (not only in `onClick`). Then it should work.

**UPDATE**

Also taking the answer from @Reza in account you could add else blocks to your if statements to set your default color like this:

```
if (holder.tv_country.getTag()!=null){
        if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnpex")) {
            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnpvg")){
            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnpgd")){
            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnpfr")){
            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnppr")){
            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        } else {
            //SET DEFAULT COLOR HERE
        }
        if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnsex")) {
            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnsvg")) {
            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnsgd")) {
            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnsfr")) {
            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        }else if (holder.tv_country.getTag().equals("btnspr")) {
            getResult2symmetry.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
        }
        else {
            //SET DEFAULT COLOR HERE
        }
    }
```

Another possibility (just because I prefer switches over those long if-else if blocks would be a switch:

```
if (holder.tv_country.getTag()!=null){
        switch (holder.tv_country.getTag()) {
            case "btnpex":
            getResult2polish.append(str + ",");
            addbackccolor(holder.tv_country);
            break;
            //other cases...
            default:
                //SET DEFAULT COLOR HERE
        }
    }
```

Comment: means in onBindViewHolder(...) {...} method i have to again set default back ground color ?

Comment: yes - you have to reset your whole cell in `onBindViewHolder` (also important if you set a view's visibility to View.GONE somewhere in code or other stuff that affects the layout of the cell)

Comment: i add default background to button at  outside of on click of button  it works for my problem but new issue created when i scroll RecylerView  it remove the color of selected button

Comment: To fix this bug just add `else` blocks as @Reza.Abedini just posted

Comment: i try this but when i scroll my recylerview it change the selected button background@Katharina

Comment: oh sorry - you need to add `else { //SET DEFAULT COLOR }` to all your if blocks and remove the code where you set the default color from the location you added it in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

You can save the state of button in array or list and apply to it in onViewBind. Use xml file to change colors according to state.

Comment: how can i save state of button in array? can you write in my code?@Prathmesh Patil

Comment: save it in form of boolean i.e for pressed state true and false for default.

Comment: but i have multiple button and which dynamically added so how to identified the true or false state button

Comment: if buttons are added dynamically then use list instead of array, and add element in list when button adds.

Comment: at click time add it to list?